# Store python variables into an xml file

Tags: python, xml, parsing, variables, store

i need to store python variables (int, bool, string, list of bool) into an xml file.
In addition, i need to store a python script inside this xml file.
I explain better:
i want to read a python .py script, store it in the xml file. After that, i want to read it from the xml, and write it to a file(maintaining all the spaces and lines).

For parsing the xml i'm using import xml.etree.ElementTree (as suggested in diveintopython3 )

Is there a way?
Thank you in advance

Comment: "is there a way" for doing what exactly? What is the particular problem? What is the exact problem you are facing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To store a text in an XML node preserving its formatting you can use:

- a [CDATA section](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp), like `<![CDATA[`*text with fancy formatting*`]]>`.
- a base-64 encoded string — this is good for binary data, too.